# MongoDB autcomplete returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, autocomplete

I am using mongodb's sample movie database (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/sample-data/sample-mflix#std-label-sample-mflix) to experiment with mongodb's autocomplete functionality. The search always returns an empty array. I have set up a Search Index as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "title": [
        {
          "minGrams": 3,
          "tokenization": "edgeGram",
          "type": "autocomplete"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The model and the search query are setup as follows:

```
// Creating the Movies model
const Movies = mongoose.model("Movies", new mongoose.Schema({}), "movies");

// Implementing autocomplete search
app.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await Movies.aggregate([
      {
        $search: {
          autocomplete: {
            path: "title",
            query: req.query.title,
            fuzzy: {
              maxEdits: 2,
              prefixLength: 3,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      results: result.length,
      data: { result },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I am using postman to run test queries and a sample query is: 127.0.0.1:3030/search?title=black

The model can be queried using .find(), for example, and returns the full collection of documents.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are asking about MongoDB, use mongo shell for the reproduce code and not javascript using an odm.

Comment: loosely related: is your db local or Atlas?

Comment: Thanks @D.SM. What is the reasoning behind your suggestion?

Comment: @Minsky db is Atlas.

Comment: @eest is it the free tier? If so, you can't have complex indexes.

Comment: @Minsky - ooh darn. Looking at https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations the aggregation limitations don't seem to be a problem. There is a collections limit of 500 (which is odd given I am using a sample DB provided by mongodb). Will investigate further - would be good to definitively determine this is the problem. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: no worries and good luck. will take a look later too.

Comment: Either your question includes irrelevant information or you are confused as to what you are working with and what you are asking about.

Comment: @D.SM maybe both. If you could elaborate on your earlier comment it might help me better articulate my question.